# How to perform torture attacks?

Tags: bayonetta

What is the condition to enable torture attacks?
Is it the same condition for all enemies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one full bar of magic to do a torture attack which I think adds up to 8 orbs.

Torture attacks are based on where the angel is at relevant to Bayonetta. For example, if it's in front of Bayonetta and facing her, Bayonetta will use the iron maiden. If it's in front of Bayonetta but *not* facing her, she'll use the guillotine.

Once you have 8 orbs, the option will show up by default.